# What is the difference between Trailer and Movie when creating a new one in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

The problem is as it is on the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trailers methodology was designed for brief (~1 minute) movies, and it provides lots of pre-designed visual and audio templates (background music, essentially) to help make the process simpler.

These links may help: [How to create iMovie 10 trailers](http://www.macworld.com/article/2069025/how-to-create-imovie-10-trailers.html), Apple's [convert trailers to movies](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14712?locale=en_US), and [How to Create a Movie Trailer in iMovie](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_create_movie_trailer_imovie).